# JSF/CDI: End Conversation after page renders?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi, conversation-scope

I have a situation where I have a multi-step wizard rendered using JSF 2.2, and deployed on Wildfly 10/JBoss EAP.  Our wizard exists within a CDI `Conversation` to maintain state across all of the pages.  Once the last step of the wizard completes, a record is saved to the database, and I call `conversation.end()` to end the workflow.  I would like to display a value that exists within my Conversation scope to indicate to the user that the process has completed.  However, when I end my `Conversation`, the value obviously goes away because it was set in `Conversation` scope.

Is there a way to tell CDI to end my `Conversation` after the final page has completed rendering?  Is there a better way to handle the management of the `Conversation`?

Comment: I'm very rusty on this but couldn't you just hold the value you want to show in a `@SessionScoped` or `@ViewScoped` annotated bean?

Comment: Or a `@ViewAccessScoped` from DeltaSpike?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to manipulate conversation scope as you would like to. Unless you could invoke `conversation.end()` after you redirect the user and display the value. But that would no longer fit into the wizard's lifecycle.

But a relatively simple way around that is using any broader scope that outlives the conversation and storing the value there. To stick with pure CDI, I'd go for `@SessionScoped` (after all, conversations live within session).

Shortly before you invoke `conversation.end()`, store the desired value into session scoped bean variable and display it from there.

Comment: I'd go for viewAccessScoped from Delta Spike... It is 'pure cdi' but an extension. Not a custom framework

Comment: True, but you need to bring in DeltaSpike dependency to get that one. And a lot of people are against adding anything extra or are even forbidden to do so by project manag/lead. So I just tried to state the minimal way.

Comment: Sort or indeed happening a lot.... But... In my (sometimes not so) humble opinion, any project-lead that is against adding good existing **extensions** like Delta Spike or OmniFaces (or even PrimeFaces) and requires custom code to be written instead or using the relatively complex conversation constructs where a viewaccesscoped would be a great fit should be fired ;-) (I'm against explicit project leads or 'architects' anyway. The team should be the project lead and/or architect.)